# Jackson2 Java to Json array ignore field names when creating array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jsonserializer

I'm trying to create a Java REST endpoint which returns a JSON data array to be consumed by JQuery FLOT charting plugin.

At a minimum, the JSON data for FLOT needs to be an array of numbers i.e.

```
[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
```

Given I have a List of Point objects in Java i.e.

```
List<Point> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

where Point is defined as

```
public class Point {

    private final Integer x;
    private final Integer y;

    public Point(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    ...
 }
```

What methods or Jackson2 annotations, if any, do I need to put on the Java objects to get the correct JSON format. Currently I am getting the output in this format:

```
[{x:x1, y:y1}, {x:x2, y:y2} ...]
```

When I need this format:

```
[[x1,y1], [x2,y2] ...]
```

Comment: What you need is not a valid json..

Comment: I was just outlining the differences between the formats rather than full syntax :)

Comment: @mserioli the final Flot format is valid JSON... Arrays of Arrays... the trick is Ayub needs a custom Jackson "Object Mapper/Resolver" to return the x,y as an array vs. as a map. (I'm not sure what the Jackson term is for this mapper/resolver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `Point` serializer

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

public class CustomPointSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Point> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Point point, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        gen.writeNumber(point.getX());
        gen.writeNumber(point.getY());
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

then you can set your custom serializer class to your `Point` class

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize(using = CustomPointSerializer.class)
public class Point {

    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;

    public Point(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Integer x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Integer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(Integer y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

and try it

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new Point(1,2));
points.add(new Point(2,3));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(points));
```

the code produces the following result

```
[[1,2],[2,3]]
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I used a slightly modified version of this answer but yes it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @JsonView annotation on a special getter method which returns an array of intergers. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonObjectAsArray {
    static class Point {

        private final Integer x;
        private final Integer y;

        public Point(Integer x, Integer y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public int[] getXY() {
            return new int[] {x, y};
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new Point(12, 45)));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[ 12, 45 ]
```

Comment: JsonValue, as written in the example, not JsonView at the top of the answer